# Thread.Sleep() or while()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi, optimization

I have a C# application in which I interact with another window via the Windows API: (e.g., `FindWindow()`, `FindWindowEx()`).

In one specific part of my application, I have to wait for the window of the other application to load before clicking the button that appears (sometimes it takes up to three seconds to show itself).

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
IntPtr foohWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
while(foohWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
    foohWnd = FindWindow(null, "Foo");
```

As you can see, this just keeps checking for a window over and over and over without being concerned about resources or anything like that. (Don't worry, in my actual code, it "times out" after a bit to prevent an infinite loop).

However, the other way I have found to do this is by using `Thread.Sleep()`:

```
Thread.Sleep(3000);
foohWnd = FindWindow(null, "Foo");
```

Which one of these two is the better practice? Is there an even better way I'm disregarding here?

Comment: Why not combine them to you sleep in your loop so that you don't peg the CPU?

Comment: Neither are particularly satisfactory. In an ideal world you get the other process to call you back when it is ready. If that process is out of your control, then use a while loop, but inject a short sleep into it to avoid making the CPU get hot.

Comment: "Is there an even better way..." - maybe, depends on why you've chosen to go down to the Windows API level in the first place. E.g. using UI Automation so that you can interact at a more semantic level may be appropriate. We don't know what you do once you've *found* this window.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever As I said in my question, I need to click a button. That's all. The rest of the code is in place, and works. I just want to know if the way I'm doing this is an atrocity or not. (I'm a self-conscious programmer). Plus, I have no control over the other process.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah, I see. Okay. Thank you. The process is indeed out of my control, so I shall mix both approaches.

Comment: Had you asked about your problem (rather than your proposed solution), I would have recommended [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx). They were invented for precisely the problem you are trying to solve (using the wrong solution).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

It is asynchronous way and the thread won't be blocked.

Comment: I've decided to go this route for now, thanks @Tito.

Comment: Right answer to the wrong solution. The OP really needs to use [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx), because that is how you wait for a window to be created. Suspending threads is working around a problem caused by choosing the wrong solution.

Comment: Echoing IInspectable's sentiment, but adding: So if the thread won't be blocked what happens during the await? A modal message loop? Because anything else does not make particular sense...

Comment: @IInspectable I eventually ended up going this route. Thanks for your comment. I know this is old and all, just going through my only negative questions and trying to turn them into something more helpful to the community.

Comment: @Ellis: You should consider writing up an answer, instead of editing a solution into your question. That makes it easier for future visitors to find a solution to their problem. SO is all about persisting valuable information. Being old doesn't mean, that a Q&A should receive less diligence.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix both aproches:

```
IntPtr foohWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
while(foohWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    foohWnd = FindWindow(null, "Foo");
}
```

While consmes CPU, but only sleep doesn't work when window apears after more than 3 sec.